# Jediscluster with Object pool

Tags: java, redis, pool, jedis

I am new to Jedis, found [here](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis)

I want to make pool of **JedisCluster** objects, using the constructor found as:

```
 public JedisCluster(Set<HostAndPort> nodes, final GenericObjectPoolConfig poolConfig) {
      this(nodes, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTIONS, poolConfig);
 }
```

Now my doubt is, is this implementation going to handle the pool internally or I have to use the Apache Commons Pool to handle the objects of JedisCluster?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

JedisCluster stores pools for each node internally, and poolConfig is for setting up these pools.

Hope this helps.

Thanks!